# Помогите понять в чем ошибка с Thread?

Tags: c#

Вопрос в следующем, есть такой метод

```
public async Task<AuctionRequest[]> GetBids(ICollection<RtbModel> rtb_partners, AuctionModel auctionModel)
        {
            var bids = new Task<AuctionRequest>[rtb_partners.Count];
            int i = 0, j = 0;

            foreach (var advert in rtb_partners)
            {
                if (advert == null)
                    throw new Exception("Dsp not found");

                var protocol = advert.Protocol;
                string protocolVersion = protocol switch
                {
                    RtbProtocolEnum.OpenRTB_2_2 => "2.2",
                    RtbProtocolEnum.OpenRTB_2_3 => "2.3",
                    RtbProtocolEnum.OpenRTB_2_4 => "2.4",
                    RtbProtocolEnum.OpenRTB_2_5 => "2.5",
                    _ => throw new NotSupportedException("RTB protocol not supported")
                };

                var bidRequest = BuildBidRequestModel(auctionModel[j++]);

                bids[i++] = await ProcessBidRequest(bidRequest, advert.Endpoint, protocolVersion);
            }

            return await Task.WhenAll(bids);
        }
```

который внутри себя в цикле вызывает метод

```
public async Task<AuctionRequest> ProcessBidRequest(BidRequestModel requestModel, string endpoint, string protocol)
{
 //Код выполнения
}
```

Но код не выполнятся так как появляется вот такая ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
**не могу понять как можно ее исправить, помогите**

P.S.
`AuctionRequest` представляет из себя структуру

```
public struct AuctionRequest
        {
            public readonly BidRequestModel bidRequest;
            public readonly BidResponseModel bidResponse;
            public readonly string rtbProtocol;

            public AuctionRequest(BidRequestModel requestModel, BidResponseModel responseModel, string protocolEnum)
            {
                bidRequest = requestModel;
                bidResponse = responseModel;
                rtbProtocol = protocolEnum;
            }
        }
```

Comment: @gil9red, какой ещё стек, у него ошибка компиляции. И зачем он тебе нужен?

Comment: @Qwertiy, ага,сглупил :)

Comment: @gil9red, на скриншоте есть возвращаемый тип метода. А тип переменной есть в коде выше.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а, понял... await выполнил таску и вернул AuctionRequest из-за этого в `bids[i++] = ` и случилась ошибка. Правильно?

Comment: @gil9red, ага, так.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> bids[i++] = await ProcessBidRequest(bidRequest, advert.Endpoint, protocolVersion);
> ```

```
bids[i++] = ProcessBidRequest(bidRequest, advert.Endpoint, protocolVersion);
```

Comment: Да, но мне надо, чтобы задача выполнялась асинхронно

Comment: Так вы и вызываете же потом все задачи одновременно. return await Task.WhenAll(bids);

Comment: @Nikita вы бы попробовали для начала.

Comment: @Nikita, вот и надо убрать await.